# Stack Overflow Teams has a bug in signup process

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-for-teams

### Context

When signing up for Stack Overflow Teams, you go through three steps:

1. Provide a valid email
2. Select a team name
3. Choose a payment plan

If you decide for not complete the signup process, you will receive emails sometime in the future reminding you to finish signing up (if you so wish). This is important, because it means that Stack Overflow records fields before you even finalize the signup process

### Bug

If you abort a signup after entering a team-name, that team-name is no longer available. This basically lows the pool of available team names since people who aren't committed to the signup process will eliminate names inadvertently.

### Replication

1. Get a temporary email with TempMail
2. Go to the SO Teams signup and enter that email.
3. Proceed to pick a team name you are pretty sure is unique (it will tell you if it isn't)
4. Close the browser
5. On another computer browser, or after clearing your browser cookies, repeat steps 1-2
6. Repeat step 3, but with the team name you last picked, you will see the team name is no longer available.

#### Summary

You can permanently remove team names from the space of available team names without actually committing to creating a team.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is intentional! When you're going through the creation wizard we reserve the team URL slug for 30 mins on a sliding interval as you go through the process. This is to prevent somebody swiping a slug from you prior to completing purchase of your team.

The reservation is tied to your registered account, if you have one, and so is transported across different browsers. If you're anonymous it is tied to a specific browser session (read: cookies) which is the behaviour you were seeing.

After 30 minutes the slug is freed for use by others if checkout wasn't completed.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know about this. I tested the signup (without checking out) and then sent a link to another coworker to complete team-creation. We then realized the name was no longer available.